# Calculating the mass of an object in an Atwood machine system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

Sorry if the title doesn't represent my question correctly, I'm just learning physics and so I don't know what a proper title would be to describe the problem. I would be more than happy to be corrected for next time.

For the question at hand.

I have the given diagram:
[image]
The mass of the rope is insignificant and there's no friction between the wheel and the rope.
I need to find the mass `m` given these parameters:
$
M = 40kg\\
\theta = 30°\\
a = 0.5g\hspace{20pt}\text{(acceleration uphill of M)}\\
\mu_k = \mu_s = 0.231
$

Now this is what I came up with:

$
\sum F_x = T - Mg\sin \theta - \mu_kMg\cos \theta = 0\\
T - 40g\sin(30°) - 0.231 \cdot 40g\cos(30°) = 0\\
T = 117.57N\\[20pt]
\sum F_y = T - mg = -ma\\
T = mg - ma\\
T = ma\\
117.57 = 0.5mg\\
m = 24kg
$

Now according to the book the answer is $m = 96kg$ and so I got this wrong.
For their calculation of $\sum F_x$ the did the following:
$
T - Mg\sin\theta - \mu Mg\cos\theta = \frac{1}{2}Mg
$

And they made the net force on the x axis equal $0.5Mg$.
I made it equal to `0` because I thought that since a kinetic force is acting upon the object with mass `M` then the object is thus moving at constant speed so $a = 0 \implies \sum F_x = am = 0$
But I guess I'm wrong about that so I don't understand this part because as far as I know if there's a kinetic force the object moves at a constant speed so the acceleration should be zero.

Comment: Welcome to the website. Please use mathjax to format your equations.

Comment: @RedGiant I am.. using it?

Comment: There is one picture of an equation.

Comment: @RedGiant I've made it a picture because that was taken from the answers book so I've preferred it to be a picture emphasizing that I didn't wrote it and just pictured it from the book. Anyway wrote it up.

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstood the question but kinetic friction can also occur on an accelerating body. The net force is 0.5Mg because the acceleration is given (0.5g)

Comment: @EricZhang you're correct. Someone already explained it to me. I just assumed that the body is moving at a constant speed after kinetic friction was introduced. I guess it's hard for me to understand what's being conveyed in questions sometimes and I assume the wrong things.

Comment: Can you retype the question as it's written? I think you left out some details.

Comment: The problem is indeterminate as stated.  The static friction coefficient is unknown.  Also, there is a range of masses "m" that would result in the large block not moving either down the incline or up the incline.  If the large block is moving, you need to know if it is moving down the incline or up the incline, and you need to know the acceleration of the large block.

Comment: @DavidWhite Can I understand your thinking process? You're correct about the range of masses "m" that would result in the large block not moving either down the incline or up the incline. This was the last section of the question actually, finding `m` while the system is at rest (`a = 0`). But only after comparing my answer on this section of the question to the book answers I've been shown that there's a range of masses `m` that causes the system to be a rest. What I'm asking actually is how you identified this without solving anything, what is the intuition here that gave it away for you?

Comment: @DavidWhite Also the static friction coefficient was missing because of a typo of mine. Should be fixed now.

Comment: The static friction coefficient is not equal to the kinetic friction coefficient.  In addition, you didn't say whether the large mass is moving at constant speed or accelerating.

Comment: @DavidWhite The question states that the coefficients equals.
And you're correct, `a = 0.5g` is the acceleration of `M` uphill.

Answer (score 1):

What you did wrong: When finding tension, you assumed the system was in equilibrium (i.e. at rest/moving at constant speed). The system, however, is not in equilibrium, as implied by the given acceleration value.

---

Note: it is unclear in which direction the system accelerates. I will just assume that mass $m$ is accelerating downwards.

Before I hint at the approach, I will elaborate on the following:

> You can calculate the net force on the whole system (both blocks). You can also calculate the net force on an individual block.

The beauty of calculating the net force on the whole system is that internal forces (like the tension) cancel out.

The force of gravity on $m$ is accelerating the system in what I will declare as the positive direction. So we have $+mg$. Next up, we have a component of the force of gravity on $M$ pulling the opposite way, so we have $-Mg\sin\theta$. We also have the friction, so that's $-\mu_kMg\cos\theta$. Putting it all together, we get:

***(try to get the following equation yourself, before revealing the spoiler)***

> $$mg-Mg\sin\theta-\mu_kMg\cos\theta=(m+M)a$$

Notice that tension is not in this equation (which is good, one less variable to worry about).

From there, use the relationship you have for the acceleration $a$, you can solve for $m$.

**Note:** you can also solve this problem using your approach (by solving for tension first), but it's just more needless work. However, I encourage you to use both approaches to convince yourself that they indeed arrive at the same result.

Comment: So far in my book problems were solved by calculating the net force on each component so this is the way I've learn to do it so far, it's nice to see this approach of the whole system actually, thanks!
Can you explain why the tension was left out from the equation of the net force of the whole system? Not so clear to me

Comment: The tensions were not left out. They simply cancelled. If this confuses you, post a separate question asking that (hard to provide a complete answer in the comments).